# How to fix "html5 assets malformed" while uploading pixi.js ad to google?

Tags: javascript, html, admob, pixi.js

I made a playable ad in javascript using pixi.js but I encoutered an issue while uploading my zip to google (html5 assets are malformed). I'm pretty sure that pixi is causing the error, because it works when I upload my ad without pixi.js.
Does anyone how to fix this?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the XHR and XDR function inside pixi.js. You can find the minfied version of the working script (legacy!) here: https://gist.github.com/mbpictures/2dd4177aca97f8a92f9c3d162cd2f4b3

Comment: Maybe this should be reported as issue in pixi.js github https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues - what you think @MBPictures ? I mean maybe some option should be added to pixi to disable such features if someone needs it in future.

Comment: @domis86 yeah, I reported it. Thx for the hint ;)